# Разбиение строки на знаки пунктуации и последовательности остальных символов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

С помощью функций `preg_match_all('~[,()^/*+-]~', $e, $m)` и `preg_split("/\,|\(|\)|\^|\/|\*|\-|\+/",$e);` я разбиваю строку в массив по определенным словам.

**Мне надо разделять строку по словам, отличным от `,`, `(`, `)`, `^`, `/`, `*`, `-`, `+` и не отличным от них.**

Например:

```
pi*t+(a/c)
```

В `array(array('*','+','/'),array(pi,t,a,c))`.

Мой `preg_split("/\,|\(|\)|\^|\/|\*|\-|\+/",$e);` оставляет пустые элементы в получаемом массиве.

Comment: Что это вы имеете в виду? Запятая не слово, как и остальные знаки `()^/*-+`. Приведите пример.

Comment: `[^,\(\)\^\/\*\-\+]` - используется подобный синтаксис. Знаком отрицания служит `^`

Comment: @iosp: Только без слешей - `[^,()^/*+-]`. Может, `preg_split('~[^,()^/*+-]+~', $e)`? Без примеров трудно понять, что именно требуется.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew не уверен насчёт слэшей, обычно экранирую спецсимволы в рег. выражении. Точно не вредит.

Comment: Пример(ы) приведите. В самом вопросе, не в комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо разбиения строки, необходимо найти все совпадения искомых символов с помощью `preg_match_all`:

```
// Всё вместе
$e = "a+d+c/t-(a*r)";
preg_match_all('~[^,()^/*+-]+|[,()^/*+-]~', $e, $m); 
print_r($m[0]);
// Только все "слова"
preg_match_all('~[^,()^/*+-]+~', $e, $m1); 
print_r($m1[0]);
// Только все "символы"
preg_match_all('~[,()^/*+-]~', $e, $m2); 
print_r($m2[0]);
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/jqNt3N)

Так как в качестве разделителей используется `~`, обратный слеш экранировать `/` не нужно. Так как `-` помещен в конец символьного класса его экранировать тоже не надо. `^` не в начальной позиции в символьном классе тоже экранировать не надо. `,()*+` в символьных классах трактуются буквально всегда.

Comment: Вопрос я изменил

Comment: @lexakop Т.е. нужно получить массив "токенов". Ответ обновлен.

Comment: Спасибо, вы меня правильно поняли, все работает.